# Creating Symbolic Link to directory with spaces in name

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Trying to create a symbolic link to a directory on networked computer. The directory has a space in the name.

This works fine:

```
mklink /d "C:\Jobs" "\\BECFILESERVER01\Documents\Jobs"
```

but I want my link to point to a sub-directory called "*Commercial Jobs*"
I have tried this:

```
mklink /d "C:\Jobs" "\\BECFILESERVER01\Documents\Jobs\Commercial Jobs"
```

It creates the link but I get an error when I try to access the link through windows explorer:

*"Location is not available. C:\Jobs refers to a location that is unavailable...."*

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: Failed to reproduce your problem in Windows 10. I successfully created a link to a folder name that has space in it.

Comment: In linux the proper syntax for a space is something like "\Comercial/ Jobs". Is it something similar in windows?

Comment: I am using command prompt in  Windows 7 if that makes a difference.  When I run the command, command prompt tells me that it successfully created the link but when I click on the link in explorer, thats when I get the error.  If I link to a directory without a space in the name, then it creates the link and I am able to click on it in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.  I was using the correct syntax and it works now.  The problem was that the person who created the sub-directory "Commercial Jobs" had misspelled it "Commerical Jobs".  I've used that directory for a couple of years now and never noticed the misspelling.
Thanks for your help Fleet Command.  When you said you recreated it without an issue, then I knew I had to be doing something wrong.  This is the first time is used this forum.

Comment: Lesson: mklink doesn't check if source is a valid file/folder. right?